# Show Bootstrap Responsively

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I have a project, I would like the "Nav" to be shown on the phone just as it does on a computer or notebook.

My Notebook:

```
1º 2º 3º
```

My Phone:

```
1º
2º
3º
```

My Ex Code:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">1º</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">2º</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">3º</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">ex:1º</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">ex:2º</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">ex:3º</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of adding the correct amount of columns inside of a row.

You should check out the Grid System

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-4">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">1º</a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-4">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">2º</a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-4">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">3º</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: was top, but is selected without being able to choose another option, for example, if I choose "1st", I can't choose "2nd" or "3rd" because "1st" is selected

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs row" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active col-4" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">1º</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link col-4" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">2º</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link col-4" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">3º</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

By the above code it has column size of 33.33%(col-4) on all screen sizes and the data 1º, 2º, 3º will be aligned on the same row.

You can learn about the row and column (Grid-system) in Bootstrap.
Or if you want to continue only with **HTML** and **CSS** then learn about `float{}` in css to make it align in that way.
One more way is just to set set width to each element and float it but it looks awkward when you give more content in to a element.
So the best way is to learn with bootstrap and continue on your project.